# Artifacts in Editor Window : Wrong Eclipse Configuration or Bug?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, configuration

I am using Eclipse (Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) Build id: 20180917-1800 OS: Linux, v.4.9.0-8-amd64, x86_64 / gtk 2.24.31
Java version: 1.8.0_181) under Debian Linux.

I have two problems and I do not know if they are related, whether they are caused by some incorrect configuration on my side or whether they are bugs. I have been searching on different search engines for the past few days but I have found no relevant information.

The first problem appears when I start Eclipse from the command line. I get the following errors:

```
[org.eclipse.text] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.manipulation.JavaElementLabelComposerCore [Xlint:cantFindType]
[org.eclipse.jdt.core] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.manipulation.JavaElementLabelComposerCore [Xlint:cantFindType]
[org.scala-ide.sdt.aspects] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.manipulation.JavaElementLabelComposerCore [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

The second problem occurs very frequently in the editor. Here is an example screenshot take just before the problem occurs:[image: Editor is still OK]
Now I positioned the cursor after the end of the line

```
System.out.println("Hello, world!");
```

and hit enter. As a result, one or more line beneath the cursor disappear and artefacts (e.g. partial copies of the side panel) appear on the editor area, as shown in the following picture:[image: Editor is broken]

Note that the missing lines are still there. The editor gets cleaned up if I force a repaint, e.g. by saving the file with CTRL-S.

My questions:

- Can the problem in the editor be related to some misconfiguration?
- Is the misconfiguration (or missing library) related to the errors that appear during start up?

Comment: The errors seem to come from a third party plugin that uses AspectJ (load time weaving) and not from Eclipse itself. Can you reproduce this issue with a plain Eclipse without additional plug-ins?

Comment: @howlger: Thanks for the hint! I unpacked a fresh copy of Eclipse and started from there. The error message in the terminal has disappeared. The editor is still messed up though. So, the two problems are not related.

Comment: Maybe it's a GTK 2.x issue which is used if GTK 3.x is not available. Are there ways to install GTK 3.x?

Comment: @howlger: Package `libgtk-3-0` was already installed. I have additionally installed `gtk3-engines-breeze` and `gtk3-engines-xfce` but the problem persists. Several `gtk2` engines are already installed.

Comment: Is it the same if you do `export SWT_GTK3=0` vs. `export SWT_GTK3=1` before starting Eclipse from the command line?

Comment: @howlger: With `export SWT_GTK3=1` the problem in the editor seems to be gone!! On the other hand, I have several other error messages in the terminal: `Gdk-WARNING **: The GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS environment variable is not supported in GTK3.`, `GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed`, `Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to GtkScrolledWindow 0x7fc020cb5400 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?`, `Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar`.

Comment: Did you upgrade to 2018-09 or newly installed it? I'm wondering why `SWT_GTK3=1` is not the default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183500/discussion-between-giorgio-and-howlger).